# Loading dynamic html - reading from config and load html Ionic 2 Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to cross-platform and ionic framework.

we have several retailers, their HTML pages and designs may be different from their requirement but mostly all backend functionalities are same.

For example, the retailer1 login page is different but the logic for login is same for all retailers.

my project structure looks like

```
    Project Name
       .src
        .. app
        .. assert
        .. pages
              ... Login
                   .... retailer1Login.html
                   .... retailer2Login.html
                   .... Login.scss
                   .... Login.ts
```

`Login.ts` class should route to HTML file depends on the config file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: {{this.htmlPage}},
})

export class SembCorpLoginPage {
  htmlPage : any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }




     ngOnInit() {
        console.log("App.Components")
        if(CONFIG.retailerName == CONSTANTS.retailer1){
          this.htmlPage = retailer1LoginPage;
          console.log("Apps if pageLoader");
        }else {
          this.htmlPage = retailer2LoginPage;
          console.log("Apps else");
        }
        console.log(this.htmlPage);
      }

      ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
      }
```

In order to maintain single code base system, we have a config file, but that config parameters are different from retailer to retailer.

read the config file in `Login.ts` and depend on html file load the html file.

is it possible to do like this. I got error. I couldn't run futher.

any helps or guides?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to use [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

You can also take a look on [sample implementation](https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d)